# Proof that nuclear norm minimization gives a unique solution

Tags: matrices, nuclear-norm, matrix-completion

I am reading a paper "A simpler approach to matrix completion", which talks about matrix completion using nuclear norm minimization. In section 4 it proofs that, the optimization problem gives a unique solution which is equal to the desired matrix.

It says that it uses dual feasibility approach to prove it, but I am not able to understand the proof at all. Can someone help?!

---

[image]

Comment: Can you state the optimization problem exactly?

Comment: Added the page of paper containing the optimization problem.

Comment: Basically in this post I am asking to explain the intuition behind prove of theorem 1.1, given in section 4 of this paper.

Comment: It would be nice to have a link to the paper